# passing a type as a parameter in C

Tags: c

I'm writting a function where I have the parameter "size", and depending of the value of size, I would use the type unsigned char, unsigned short or unsigned int.
Typically, I'm trying to do something like that :

```
if (size == 1) {unsigned char * memory = calloc(sizeOfFile,1);}
if (size == 2) {unsigned short * memory = calloc(sizeOfFile,1);}
if (size == 4) {unsigned int * memory = calloc(sizeOfFile,1);}
```

where i could use "memory" outside of the "if".
Is there any way to do that or do I have to copy my function 3 times into each "if" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you do with `memory` after it has been allocated? Your example lets it go out of scope; I assume that's not what happens in the real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of passing a type to a C function, because a type is a compile-time concept. Once the compiler is finished, there's no type to talk about: the knowledge of the types is "baked into" the binary code the compiler generates, with no additional metadata to make available to your program.

Instead of passing a type, you can pass a size, and do pointer math by yourself. Take [`qsort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) or [`bsearch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/bsearch.html) functions as an example: they both work on untyped arrays as if they knew the exact type. The "magic" that lets these functions do it is in the `size_t nel` parameter, and a function pointer taking `const void *` arguments.

You can model your API in the same way. You are taking the `size` as a parameter already, so what's remains is the pointer math. Convert the pointer to `char *` so that adding `size` would advance the pointer to the next element of the "type", perform the arithmetics to advance the pointer to your target, and then convert the pointer back to `void*`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a relatively small function you can write a macro:

```
#define FOO(T, x, y, z) do \
{ \
    T * memory = calloc(sizeOfFile, 1); \
    ... \
    ... \
    ... \
} while(0)
```

which you would then call as, e.g.

```
FOO(char, x, y, z);
```

or

```
FOO(int, x, y, z);
```

It's ugly, and the usual caveats about macros apply, but in some cases it might be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd just use a `void *` pointer and keep track of the type in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

Your allocations all allocate a `sizeofFile` bytes, which is probably not what you want to be doing.

You could use a `void *` pointer, but that will require that you check the type when accessing later of course.

It would be easier to help you if your question was more concrete, I think.